# Will passing `this` inside of a `.Where` clause's predicate cause it to mutate?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Using Entity Framework, and wrapping a DbContext in a class like this:

```
public class Demo : IDisposable
{
  internal DbContext context;
  internal int PrivateId = 5;      

  public Demo()
  {
   this.context = new MyDbContext();
  }
  public void Question()
  {
   //Is there going to be a problem using `this` in the predicate
   var issue = this.context.SomeTable.Where(st => st.ForeignKeyId == this.PrivateId);
  }
  public Dispose()
  {
   this.context.Dispose();
  }
}
```

This is as simple of a demo as I could come up with. I was unsure if `this` would somehow be changed or modified when used as part of the predicate to `Where`. Basically I just wanted to double check because I was uncertain. I checked out [Jon Skeet's re-implementation of `Where`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot.aspx) but it was still not entirely clear that `this` would retain its value.

My uncertainty stems from the issue that predicates are passed as `Func` when used with deferred execution. As a result, it would seem that the reference for `this` could be used at a later time instead of immediately when `Where` is called.

Am I over-thinking the situation, or is there a possibility of `this` changing?

Comment: Property values of `this` certainly could change.

Comment: The class reference itself though, won't

Comment: The class reference was the part that I was curious about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` is read-only (for reference types).  You can't change what reference `this` refers to.  The object that the reference stored in `this` variable refers to may in fact change over time.

So you can be sure that, for that code, whenever it is in fact executed it *will* use the current instance of the object, and that you won't end up referencing some entirely different `Demo` object.  It will then go to that instance and pick up the value of it's `PrivateId` variable *at that instant in time*.  So if `PrivateId` has changed for that particular instance, then the changed value is what is used.

This has nothing at all to do with the implementation of `Where`, but rather the semantics of reference types and the whole concept of deferred execution.

If you want to use the value of `PrivateId` *right now*, not when the sequence is actually iterated, then simply copy the value of that variable out into some new variable and close over *that*, like so:

```
var idCopy = this.PrivateId;
var issue = this.context.SomeTable.Where(st => st.ForeignKeyId == idCopy );
```

Answer (score 3):

No, `this` does not mutate.  You are not assigning anything to it, and it is just being used as a normal variable.

Here's another example that might make it more clear:

```
var id = "12345";
var issue = this.context.SomeTable.Where(st => st.ForeignKeyId == id);
```

What is the value of `id` after executing the `Where` statement?  It's the same as before, "12345".

`this` itself can never change, but fields within it can.  Something like `Zip` or `ForEach` might do this if you had a `this.IEnumerable` or something similar, but a simple `Where` or `Select` should not change anything.

Comment: `Zip` or `ForEach` could not change `this`.  `this` is read only for reference types.  Mutating it is *impossible*.  (Barring of course some sort of `unsafe` hack.)

Comment: @Servy I wasn't referring to reference types.  If you had a this.IEnumerable or something of the type, you could modify it.  I'll edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: You can (potentially) mutate the object referenced by the `this` variable, sure.  That's *entirely* different from saying that you can mutate `this`, because you cannot.  Also, for the record, anyone who's using `Zip` to mutate the contents of either sequence is abusing the operator.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  I should have clarified further - fields of `this` can change, but `this` cannot itself change.  I'll edit again, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem using `this` in this way. Moreover, even if you don't specify "this" the reference would still be used because `PrivateId` is defined on the class.

```
public void Question()
{
  //Is there going to be a problem using `this` in the predicate
  var issue = context.SomeTable.Where(st => st.ForeignKeyId == PrivateId);
}
```